# How to return an object from rails query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the code as below I wish to return the name of the city.

```
      <% @location = branch.major_city_state_id %>
      <% @city = Metro.select(:city).where(id: @location) %>
      <td><%= @city.select(:city) %></td>
```

However the result is as below:

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Metro:0x69de2e8>
```

I know this sounds very simple but nowhere have I found where I can simply return the data I need

How can I simply get the data I want in string format ie. the name of the city?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `city` is a column, use

```
Metro.where(id: @location).pluck(:city).first
```

Comment: I was not aware of the `pluck` command. I'll rad up more about it I'm coming from a strong SQL background so it gets irritating just trying to do simple things. Thanks